# Getting Unique entries?

Tags: plugin-development, database, query

I am querying data using the code below. In the database, there are duplicate entries for 'title', how can I get distinct values?

```
$criteria = craft()->elements->getCriteria(ElementType::Entry);
$criteria->section = 'institutions';
$query = craft()->elements->buildElementsQuery($criteria);
//$query->setDistinct('title');
$query->order('title asc');

$queryResults = $query->queryAll();
$institutions = EntryModel::populateModels($queryResults);

return $institutions;
```

Comment: Are you sure that you don't just have multiple entries with the same title? The query returned by buildElementsQuery() is already prepped to fetch only unique entries.

Comment: Yeah, there is. I only need unique records.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The query returned by buildElementsQuery() is already prepped to fetch unique entries. But it’s possible for two distinct entries to have the same title, which is why it may *look* like duplicate entries are being returned.

To only fetch entries with unique titles, do this:

```php
$query->group('content.title');
```

Answer (score 1):

The `setDistinct` method should be passed a `boolean` value.

http://www.yiiframework.com/doc/api/1.1/CDbCommand#setDistinct-detail

If that doesn't work, you may need to use the `selectDistinct` method to override the `SELECT` portion of the query. By default, this sets `distinct = true`.

http://www.yiiframework.com/doc/api/1.1/CDbCommand#selectDistinct-detail

Comment: Didnt work. I did: $criteria->selectDistinct = 'title'; and $query->selectDistinct = 'title';